# Html Audio Tag and cache

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Im currently building a Web App which plays sound files now and again via JS:

```
var sound = new Audio();
function playSound(audioUrl) {
        sound.src = audioUrl;
        sound.play();
}
playSound("/my/audio/url.wav");
```

As timing is essential i want to preload all the possible soundfiles before the user can interact with the application. im doing this simply via this snippet of code:

```
var preloader = new Audio();
preloader.addEventListener("loadeddata", checkPreload(), true);
preloader.src = audioUrl;
```

This works fine and i can see in Chromes DevTools network-section  that all the Soundfiles are loaded. Also when im playing a sound it does not make another request.
If i wait a minute however and play the sound again (without reloading the page or anything like that), then the wav file is reloaded from the webserver and taking again 200 ms of loading time.

I wonder how can i prevent this. Can i manually extend the life of the audiofile cache through some setting in the response headers on the server? Can i manipulate the Audio() Tag somehow to allow me to play the same audio without reloading it from the server?

I looked into the ServiceWorkers and AppCache, but ServiceWorkers doesent support all Browsers and AppCache seems to be also depricated on Chromium browsers, so i dont exactly know how to proceed here.

Any help would be appriciated,

cheers

Comment: Service workers are [supported in all modern browsers](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/), and [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) is the alternative to AppCache, though indexedDB is probably not the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), it will only request it once.

```js
var url;
fetch("/path/to/file")
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // now you can play all the audio, setting the src value to the url variable
    // e.g.
    playSound(url);
});
```